# Jquery Validate - SubmitHandler not firing (on localhost)

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-validate

There isn't much else to add except that when I run the exact same script on a server it works fine. The validation works in the case of errors as well as submitting the form. However for  the convenience I will at times work on the project through xampp, localhost. The problem is that the submitHandler does not fire at all. It's not a case of the validate plugin being incorrectly setup because otherwise the errors wouldn't work. I have attatched the code below

```
 function registerpage(){
        //******** Registration page functions *******//



    $("#dob").datepicker({dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy"}); // date picker plugin


    $("#register_form").validate({
            errorClass : "invalid",
            invalidHandler:function(event, validator) {$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 300);},
            submitHandler: registeruser,
            onfocusout: false,
            onkeyup: false,
            onclick: false,
            rules: {
                    firstname: {
                        required : true
                    },
                    lastname: {
                        required : true
                    },
                    email:{
                        required: true, 
                        email: true,
                        remote: { 
                            url: "/actions/emailcheck.php",
                            async: false,
                            type: "post"
                        }
                    },
                    password:{
                        required:true, 
                        minlength: 5    
                    },
                    repeat:{
                        required: true, 
                        equalTo: "#password" 
                    },
                    postcode:{
                        required: true,
                        number: true,
                        minlength: 4
                    },
                    "sport[]":{
                        required: true
                    },
                    dob : {
                        required: true,
                        date: true  
                    }          
                    },
            messages : {
                firstname: {
                    required : "Enter your first name"
                },
                lastname: {
                    required : "Enter your last name"
                },
                email:{
                    required: "Enter your email",   
                    email:"Enter a valid email",
                    remote: "Email already in use"
                },
                password:{
                    required:"Enter a password", minlength: "Password must be 5 characters long"    
                },
                repeat:{
                    required: "Enter a confirmation password", equalTo: "Repeated password does not match" 

                },
                postcode:{
                    required: "Enter postcode",
                    number: "Post code must be 4 digit number", 
                    minlength: "Post code must be 4 digit number"
                },
                dob:{
                    required: "Enter date of birth",    
                    date: "Enter valid date of birth"
                },
                "sport[]": {
                    required: "Select at least one sport"           
                }

            },

            errorContainer: $(".errorCont"), 
            errorLabelContainer: $('.errorCont ul'),
            wrapper: 'li'

    });




        /*Add user to database*/
        function registeruser(){
        //  submit user
                    disablebtn($("#regbtn"));
                    var frmsrl = $("#register_form").serialize();
                    $.post('actions/action.php',frmsrl, 
                    function(data){
                        //successfully registered
                            showpopup("reg");

                        });
        }

    }
```

Really confused as to why it works on the server but not on localhost. It's just the submitHandler that doesn't get called because the errors work fine.

Comment: on submit then what is happening

Comment: @ArunPJohny nothing at all. I even put at alert prior to the server post and it didn't work. The only thing that happens which is related to the browser is that the save password dialog is displayed from Mozilla.

Comment: You can turn on the Web Console (Firefox) to check whether there are any JavaScript error.